# How can I create a custom extension for VS Code Web and load it with URL?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

The VS Code documentation says that VS Code for the Web can be customized by [custom URLs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/vscode-web#_more-custom-urls) to deliver customized experiences with pre-installed extensions.

I was wondering if this feature is available publicly and how to create an extension that utilises the above feature?

There is a same question on GitHub regarding this feature but it was asked in 2022. https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/139839.